# Can I make WPF RadioButtons look like CheckBoxes?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, radio-button

I want to have the behavior of RadioButtons, but show them as CheckBoxes to the user.  Is this easy to do?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can easily do using a ControlTemplate. Edit the template of a CheckBox and copy it to your RadioButton.

I agree that you should do this with caution as you easily can confuse the user.

Answer (score 5):

You probably can do it, but I wouldn't reccomend it. Giving a user one thing when they expect another is seldom a good idea. :D