# How to select only one checkbox at a time in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have to keep 2 checkboxes and only one should be selected at a time. But in my following code both are getting selected. How should I achieve my functionality in WPF?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="spRoles">

<CheckBox Name="chkMale" Content="Male" />
<CheckBox Name="chkFemale" Content="Female" />

</StackPanel>
```

I have to use checkboxes only not radio buttons.

Comment: Why can't you use radio buttons? They're what's normally used for this sort of thing.

Comment: Moreover, *not using* radio buttons would confuse the user of your UI. At least if I were that user, I'd expect to be able to select multiple of a set of check boxes. With radio buttons it is immediately clear that I can only select one.

Comment: Because I have to make functionality similar to gmail settings tab. There you can put only one tick mark against an option.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Can I make WPF RadioButtons look like CheckBoxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1616212/1136211).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

listen for the select event or something similar and check the other checkbox

```
public void MaleOnSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(chkFemale.Selected)
        chkFemale.Selected=false;
}
```

clearly you have to do the same for the female checkbox

anyway as stated by other a radio button would be better, you can style it as a checkbox if that's what you need

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you should use Radio buttons.

Allowing checkboxes to select only one, it doesn't make sense.

If you still use checkboxes then whole concept of checkboxes will go off.

Answer (score 1):

In this case just use a radio button instead of Check box. Check boxes are mostly used for multiple item selection.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the vision of purpose and disagree that allowing checkboxes to select only one does not make sense. You can call the method for every checkbox in the group.

```
    private void uncheckCheckBoxes(object sender)
    {
        if (radioButtonEdit.IsChecked == true)
        {
            CheckBox currentcheckbox = (CheckBox)sender;

            foreach (var checkBox in ManyCheckBoxes.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => (bool)cb.IsChecked))
            {
                if (!currentcheckbox.Name.Equals(checkBox.Name))
                {
                    checkBox.IsChecked = false;
                }
            }
         }
    }

    private void checkbox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        uncheckCheckBoxes(sender);
    }
```